# REST API return code when the service refuses to execute a request

Tags: rest, http-status-codes

I'm developing a REST API that represents a task manager. It receives requests by "users" who want a task executed, but occasionally the service may reject the request. The request is well-formed (user is authenticated and authorized, the request message can be understood by the task manager, etc.), so no 4xx error: it is the task manager that, maybe because of excessive load or congestion, or because of its inability to manage *that* request, refuses to execute the request. Still, it may be able to execute it at a later time.

I could respond to the request with a JSON object that includes a "Request accepted" boolean, but I feel that 200 is the wrong status code to return. I should probably return another status code, which should be eloquent enough about the request being accepted or rejected. What status code should I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use 202 ACCEPTED if your API accepts the request but doesn't immediately executes it. This is not completely your case if I understand it correctly?

503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE is probably more appropriate as the service refuses to respond to the request.

> 503 SERVICE UNAVAILABLE The server is currently unable to handle the
>   request due to a temporary overload or scheduled maintenance, which
>   will likely be alleviated after some delay.

Comment: They both sound like partially acceptable codes. 202 doesn't convey the fact that the request won't be actually served. As to 503, it's not the _service_ that is currently unavailable: the service may reject your request to do the task, but it will still respond to queries about its status or to other requests. I'm not sure how strong the semantics of these codes are, and if I can adapt them to my case.

Comment: 503 only says that the service is temporally unavailable, so other requests might go trough.

Comment: I think you need at least something in the 5xx range, because your API is the one refusing the request

Comment: I totally agree with the 5xx range. I also considered 429 TOO MANY REQUESTS, but that actually means "too many requests _from that client_", so it's not it.

Comment: It shouldn't be in the 4xx range as it is not an error caused by the client's request but more of a server issue. 503 is the most appropriate status code there is for your use case.

Comment: I went with 503. Thanks for your help!